# Google Cloud Platform keeps stopping

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My VM instance (not preemptible) on Google Cloud Platform keeps stopping inexplicably. I am running scripts on 10 separate tmux sessions, which in total use about 80% of CPU. Compute stops randomly (see linked image for graph of CPU usage over time), at which point I have to click into my non-responsive terminal window to restart things. And every time I successfully get the terminal to be responsive again, 1-2 of my tmux sessions are killed... Any ideas as to why this is happening?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8HDo.png]

Comment: Don't run the CPU at 80% or higher. CPU capacity for networking connectivity becomes a problem. Increase your instance size. Edit your question with more details.

Comment: Agreed on what @JohnHanley said. Also, if you have a [support package](https://cloud.google.com/support), this would be a good point to [open a case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) and have one of the engineers take a closer look.

Comment: Check your tmux log file or start tmux with a `-v` or  `-vv` flag, this should give you a good start

Comment: Same thing happens even when I use ~40% of CPU. 
I used the -vv flag and searched the tmux log file, but was unable to learn anything useful

Answer (score 2):

If your instance has had high CPU utilization most of the time, Compute Engine recommends a machine type with more virtual CPUs.

If you determine that you want to apply the recommendations made by Compute Engine, you can resize the instance directly from the recommendations screen, or manually step through the operations that are returned when [viewing sizing recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances#how_sizing_recommendations_work).

Comment: Thanks, but the same thing happens even when I use <50% of CPU